# Android preference screen and backpress

Tags: android, android-activity, preference

I have a preference activity with a few nested preference screens. In my main activity I've added a shortcut which:

1. Loads my preference activity
2. simulates a click on one of the preference items to show one of these nested preference screens.

Now when the user clicks back, I want to go back to my main activity, instead it takes me back to the root of the preference activity.

I've tried:

1. Overwrite onKeyDown etc in preference activity  ... it won't get hit on the first "back button press". This first back press seems to be swallowed by the preferencescreen.
2. When loading my preference activity I've tried to remove it from the backstack (didn't work either as adb shell dumpsys activity shows the preference activity) 
               Intent intent = new Intent();

   ```
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
           startActivity(intent);
   ```

Comment: When you say "nested preference screens", what do you mean? More activities? Fragments?

Comment: I mean: I have preference screen #1 which contains 5 items. If you click on one of those items it opens up a new preference screen (#2) which contains a few items.                                                      So for my use case:  After loading the preference activity (via the intent), I simulate a click on one of the items in preference screen #1. This opens preference screen #2.   Now I want "backkey" to go back to the activity which launched the "preference activity" intent.

Comment: Is preference screen #1 an activity? a fragment? What about preference screen #2?

Comment: No fragments are involved. I just have one preference activity.